# how to remove unwanted help menu in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: menu, eclipse-rcp

Hi StackOverflow team ! 
     I've created an Eclipse RCP desktop application which has an extra menu called 'Help' in the menubar. I didn't create it from any of usual ways like adding actionSets extention, or creating and registering the actions from ActionBarAdvisor.java of the project. I don't need it anymore. Please, suggest me how can i remove it from my Menubar ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's sounds like the help UI plug-ins are being included within your run configuration

Couple of things to check...

-- Have a look at your application's .product file, and see which plug-ins are defined, and see if the org.eclipse.help.ui plug-in is defined (org.eclipse.help is probably defined since org.eclipse.ui.workbench requires it, but this won't cause the menu to appear)

-- If you are running within Eclipse, open Run --> Run Configurations, select the Eclipse application you are running and check the plug-ins tab. If it is launching with 'all workspace and enabled target plug-ins' then this will be picking up the help UI plug-ins too. Even if it's not set to this option, check the plug-ins ticked to see if the org.eclipse.help.ui is defined.

This configuration should only use the plug-ins required for your application. If it was created by using the 'Launch an Eclipse Application' option from within the .product file, the configuration created should match the plug-ins defined in that.

It's also worth making sure that no other plug-ins use org.eclipse.help.ui - this can be easily seen by removing it, and then pressing the 'Validate Plug-ins' button within the run configuration dialog, it will show you if anything has been broken after removing it

Comment: Thanks a lot danmec for your answer. Your TIPs really worked for my wards. I just checked the Dependencies included into the *.product file of my project and found that there was a dep. called org.eclipse.search, which I selected and removed from my project's Dependencies and it resulted what I had wished for more than 4 days. Finally thank you very very much !