# Exclude built-in import/export wizards in Eclipse Workbench

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, workbench

In eclipse workbench in `Import` view there are some pre-defined menu items, which are:

> Supplied Implementation:
>   The workbench comes preloaded with the basic import engines for files and directories.

Here they are:

[image: Import menu]

The question is: is it possible to remove them from `Import` view? Can it be done not by code but by changing some `plugin.xml` configuration files?

Comment: I think you are really trying to ask a different question.  Why do you want this functionality removed?  Most users want to see these wizards around because they are useful.

Comment: I need to remove them, because there is no need to support them in my app. Their usage requires additional eclipse bundles, which is not preferred.

Comment: You didn't mention that this was a custom RCP app.  That changes things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find an answer in this possible duplicate question: [How to remove a Category from Import wizard in Eclipse-RCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112012/how-to-remove-a-category-from-import-wizard-in-eclipse-rcp)

BTW: If you are investigating that deeper, please note that the extension point is called "activities", but that functionality is always referred to as "capabilities" in Eclipse terminology.