# Removing the Plug-in Development in New Wizard in an RCP application

Tags: git, eclipse-rcp, rcp, egit

I am currently building an RCP application, which has been quite successful till now. I face two issues (would like Add and Remove one feature from my RCP application).

1. My "New -Wizard" shows Plugin-Development which I would like to remove
2. I would like to add a Git capability to my RCP application (I tried to use Egit, but then Git only shows in new->Select a Wizard-> Git -> Git Repository).

*I'm a beginner in git. My intention is that users can add/merge their files to a central repository in Github.

[Pic of my RCP](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32354836/Error.PNG)

My

> ApplicationWorkbehcnAdvisor.java

```
    package kr;

import org.eclipse.ui.application.IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer;
import org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchAdvisor;
import org.eclipse.ui.application.WorkbenchWindowAdvisor;

public class ApplicationWorkbenchAdvisor extends WorkbenchAdvisor {

    private static final String PERSPECTIVE_ID = "kr.perspective"; //$NON-NLS-1$

//  private static final String PERSPECTIVE_ID = "org.eclipse.jdt.ui"; //$NON-NLS-1$


    public WorkbenchWindowAdvisor createWorkbenchWindowAdvisor(IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer) {
        return new ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor(configurer);
    }

    public String getInitialWindowPerspectiveId() {
        return PERSPECTIVE_ID;
    }
}
```

Comment: Something similar was described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112012/how-to-remove-a-category-from-import-wizard-in-eclipse-rcp

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want `Plug-in Development` then don't include the `org.eclipse.pde.*` plugins in your RCP.

Comment: Thank you. 
Now I think, understand the actual problem. I started with the deletion of org.eclipse.pde* but then it started showing the internal dependency of my plugin (on which my RCP is based on). on the pde's. So seems like, I need to resolve recheck my plugin internal structure again.

Any suggestions on the Git?.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use Git