# How to Hide Eclipse Menus

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am about to release an Eclipse RCP and I'd like to hide some menus such as 'Navitation', 'Window', 'Project' etc.
I can't see how to do that through activities, what is the right way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Goto

1. `Window` Select `Customize Perspective`,
2. Select `Menu Visibility` tab,
3. uncheck `Navigation, Window and Project` check boxes and click `Ok` button.

**Here are screen shots:**

**Step:1**

[image: Window - Customize Perspective]

**Step:2**

[image: Menu Visibility]

**Step:3** Finally `Eclipse Menu` looks like below one.

[image: menu]

Comment: That's how you define the perspective in Eclipse from a users point of view, but the op is creating an RCP which should have all these settings defined already.

Answer (score 1):

Those menus are contributed by related Eclipse plugins, you need to remove those plugins from the your target platform, if you don't require them.

Also I had [kind of the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8112012/how-to-remove-a-category-from-import-wizard-in-eclipse-rcp) some time ago. May be the solution specified by Martti Käärik would work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with [Alexanders](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21874324/207764) suggestion to remove the plugins that contribute to the user interface. But if those plugins are still something the user might need, you should create your own custom perspective and define what is available in that perspective. You can define your RCP to use this perspective as default.

Relevant extension point for this is `org.eclipse.ui.perspectives`. This way the default perspective is as you decide, but the RCP isn't completly crippled for users who might want to use other views.