# How to hide by default menu from custom perspective programmatically?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, perspective

I am building a plugin for my own custom perspective. In which i want to hide some default menu like navigate, run for my perspective. I don't want unnecessary menu in my perspective. How can i do that programmatically?

Comment: See if this question helps: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21872811/207764

Comment: Answer which is given in the above question is not going to help me as i want to do that programmatically. Visibility of the above menu isn't  dependent on user. I don't want the user to see those menu in my perspective.

Comment: Did you read the code of [CustomizePerspectiveDialog#okPressed](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.6/org.eclipse.ui/workbench/3.6.0/org/eclipse/ui/internal/dialogs/CustomizePerspectiveDialog.java#CustomizePerspectiveDialog.okPressed%28%29)? It's useful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue.
Following is the code which hide `navigate` menu and `project` menu from my perspective.

```
    IWorkbenchWindow window = Workbench.getInstance()
            .getActiveWorkbenchWindow();

    if (window instanceof WorkbenchWindow) {
        MenuManager menuManager = ((WorkbenchWindow) window)
                .getMenuManager();

        Menu menu = menuManager.getMenu();
        System.out.println("Menu : " + menu);

        String[] itemIds = { "navigate","Project" };
        for (String itemId : itemIds) {
            IContributionItem item = menuManager.find(itemId);
            if (item != null) {
                item.setVisible(false);
                menuManager.update();
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps anybody.

Comment: Hi, Is there any way to remove the recent perspective shortcut shown in toolbar(top right corner)  [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42874157/how-to-remove-a-perspective-from-perspective-toolbarplaced-in-the-top-right-cor?noredirect=1#comment72864372_42874157[link]