# How to remove a perspective from perspective toolbar(placed in the top right corner) programmatically

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, e4

If i select a perspective(eg. Java EE perspective) from "open perspective" combo the perspective will be opened and it will be added near to the "open perspective" icon placed in the toolbar.Upon changing multiple perspectives the respective perspectives will be added in toolbar for shortcut purpose.

I have an rcp application in which we can install selective/all plugins from the available list of plugins.First i am installing all the plugins, opening the rcp application(windows msi) and switching to "Sample" perspective.Now the sample perspective shortcut will be added to toolbar.Now i am closing the rcp application and chaging the installation by removing Sample plugin(Which Contains Sample Perspective). If i run the rcp application and click Sample perspective in the toolbar it throws null pointer exception

Note: The "Sample" perspective is removed inside the "Open perspective" combo list.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand the question, please give us more details.

Comment: Hi Greg,added description.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the exception you get is the fact that the previous perspective cannot be restored. Please confirm. This application is a dedicated application or do you reuse the workbench application?

Comment: Yes correct.The perspective cannot be restored because it was removed already.But the perspective shortcut icon is present.so either i have to remove the shortcut or else i have to display a message to user.How do i achieve this through programming?